# How do you begin a storyboard from a different thread?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

## The Problem

I'm trying to play a StoryBoard from a different thread but a  'System.InvalidOperationException' is thrown in WindowsBase.dll.

I have a custom Control, `InfoBar`, which has a StoryBoard to close it and a `System.Timers.Timer` object to do so after several seconds.

So, how do I call `BeginStoryboard()` from a different thread?

## Error Message

The exception thrown on `BeginStoryboard(sb)`:

`An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in WindowsBase.dll but was not handled in user code`

`Additional information: The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.`

## My (simplified) Code

```
private int TimerSeconds;
private System.Timers.Timer t;

public InfoBar()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    TimerSeconds = 0;
    t = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
    t.Elapsed += t_Elapsed;
}

void t_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(TimerSeconds==3)
    {
        t.Stop();
        TimerSeconds = 0;    
        System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard sb = (System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)FindResource("sbClose");
        BeginStoryboard(sb);    
    }
    else
    {
        TimerSeconds++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you can't modify UI stuff outside the UI thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the delegate on UI [dispatcher](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.aspx) which will automatically put your stuff to UI thread. You can do UI stuff only on UI thread.

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
{
      System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard sb =
            (System.Windows.Media.Animation.Storyboard)FindResource("sbClose");
      BeginStoryboard(sb);
});
```

Comment: Aha! I didn't, had to wait for the time limit, though.